# Encryption Program not working - TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, encryption, xor

I've been working on an encryption program which just encrypts a string into decimal values, and will write another program that will decrypt it. As of right now it is doing nothing with the decimal values, but when I try to XOR the binaries I'm using for encryption it returns the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./enc.py", line 53, in <module>
    encrypt()
  File "./enc.py", line 35, in encrypt
    val1 = text2[i] + decryptionKey[j]
  TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Here is the code

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2
    import sys
    def encrypt():
      text1 = raw_input("Please input your information to encrypt: ")
      text2 = []
      #Convert text1 into binary (text2)
      for char in text1:
        text2.append(bin(ord(char))[2:])
      text2 = ''.join(text2)

      key = raw_input("Please input your key for decryption: ")
      decryptionKey = []
      #Convert key into binary (decryptionKey)
      for char in key:
        decryptionKey.append(bin(ord(char))[2:])
      decryptionKey = ''.join(decryptionKey)

      #Verification String
      print "The text is '%s'" %text1
      print "The key is '%s'" %key
      userInput1 = raw_input("Is this information ok? y/n ")
      if userInput1 == 'y':
        print "I am encrypting your data, please hold on."
      elif userInput1 == 'n':
        print "Cancelled your operation."
      else:
        print "I didn't understand that. Please type y or n (I do not accept yes or no as an answer, and make sure you type it in as lowercase. We should be able to fix this bug soon.)"

      finalString = []

      if userInput1 == 'y':
        for i in text2:
          j = 0
          k = 0
          val1 = text2[i] + decryptionKey[j]
          if val1 == 0:
            finalString[k] = 0
          elif val1 == 1:
            finalString[k] = 1
          elif val1 == 2:
            finalString[k] = 0
          j += 1
          k += 1
        print finalString






encrypt()
```

If it would be easier, you can also view the source @ https://github.com/ryan516/XOREncrypt/blob/master/enc.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in text2:
```

This will not give indices of the list, but the actual characters of the string as string. You may want to use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for i, char in enumerate(text2):
```

For example,

```
text2 = "Welcome"
for i in text2:
    print i,
```

will print

```
W e l c o m e
```

but

```
text2 = "Welcome"
for i, char in enumerate(text2):
    print i, char
```

will give

```
0 W
1 e
2 l
3 c
4 o
5 m
6 e
```

Comment: Wait, is this treating the array as a Char array? I was hoping it was a Decimal Array... Sorry for being a Python Noob, but is that what the interpreter is seeing it as?

Comment: @RyanSmith If you use normal for loop with strings, it will be iterated as char arrays. Since there is no char data type in python, each and every char is treated as string in python.

Comment: But is this a Character/String array? I'm confused :(. I had hoped it was a Binary or Decimal array for Number Manipulation. Did something go wrong?

Comment: `text2 = ''.join(text2)` this line converts everything to string.